# Comando exit em PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Eu reparei que o comando `exit` funciona igual a um break, ele para de executar o bloco atual e passa para o próximo, mas qual comando pode parar todo o procedimento em PL/SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[De acordo com a documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems040.htm), para encerrar a execução da rotina você deve usar o comando `RETURN`.

Retificando uma coisa que você mencionou, o comando [`Exit`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/04_struc.htm#sthref467) seria para encerrar execução de laços.

> The EXIT statement forces a loop to complete unconditionally. When an EXIT statement is encountered, the loop completes immediately and control passes to the next statement

Em tradução livre:

> O comando `EXIT` força um laço a ser concluído incondicionalmente. Quando a declaração `EXIT` é econtrada, o laço é concluido imediatamente e o controle é passado para a linha de comando posterior ao laço

Espero que isso ajude.